# Memory address increasing by four

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, allocation, memory-address

I was doing a pointer exercise and I came across a doubt while experimenting the code. Why are these memory addresses in an array increasing by 4?

*For example my output is*

```
Value of var[0] = 2686720

Value of var[1] = 2686724

Value of var[2] = 2686728
```

Here is the code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
main ()
{
  int var[3]= {10,100,200};
  int *ptr[3],i;

  for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
  {
    ptr[i] = &var[i]; // assign the address of integer.
  }
  for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
  {
    printf("\n\nValue of var[%d] = ",i);
    printf("%d",ptr[i]);               //var[0]=10  var[1]=100   var[2]=200
  }
  getch();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do you write in your output "Value of" if actually you mean "Address of"? I guess this confuses everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First**, `var[i]` is array of type `int`. So, each element of that array will take up the size of one `int` each. The size of an `int` is `4` bytes.

**Next**, you are using `ptr[i]` to hold the address of the elements of `var` array. So, the `value` of `ptr [i]` is increased by `4` for each element.

Here, for better understanding, you should use `"%p"` or `"0x%x"` format specifier with `printf()` when dealing with pointers.

Also, you should change the print statement

```
printf("\n\nValue of var[%d] = ",i);
```

to

```
printf("\n\nAddress of var[%d] = ",i);
```

as the former is conveying wrong message. Actually the output value is the *address* for `var[i]`. If you want to print the value of `var[i]` using `ptr[i]`, you can consider using `*ptr[i]`.

Comment: Pedantic side-note: _"The size of an int is 4 bytes"_ should be: The size of an int is almost always 4 bytes, but is guaranteed to be at least 2 bytes by the standard. 99/99% of the time, it'll be 4 bytes, though. Perhaps consider adding the notes on `int32_t` as I did in my answer

Answer (score 0):

Each byte of memory is associated with an address. In your case each element of the array take 4 bytes in the memory and the address of that element is the address it's first byte.

So in your case the memory looks like this:

```
         Memory                Address

    |0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|    <-    2686720   ( &var[0] )
    |0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|    <-    2686721
    |0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|    <-    2686722
    |0|0|0|0|1|0|1|0|    <-    2686723

    |0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|    <-    2686724   ( &var[1] )
    |0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|    <-    2686725
    |0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|    <-    2686726
    |0|1|1|0|0|1|0|0|    <-    2686727

    |0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|    <-    2686728   ( &var[2] )
    |0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|    <-    2686729
    |0|0|0|0|0|0|1|1|    <-    2686730
    |1|1|1|0|1|0|0|0|    <-    2686731
```

Which means that by passing from an element to the next one, increases the address by `sizeof(type)`, in this case `sizeof(*ptr[i]) == sizeof(int)`

Comment: an int doesn't always take up 4 bytes, it _can_ depend on the implementation/architecture... the only way to be sure is to use `sizeof(int)`. In the olden days, `sizeof(int)` often was 2 (16bit), and the specifications only define a _minimum_ range, that's why C99 added the `int16_t` and `int32_t` types

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem In 32 bit systems it's 4 Bytes and since the Asker says it's increasing by 4 so this is the case!

Comment: Yes, I know that in the case of the OP an the ints are 4 bytes wide, but seeing as SO aims to serve as a reference for future users, it's important to note that the standard _does not enforce 4 byte ints_. Considering C code has always been meant to be as portable as possible, I wanted to point out the more consistent (and thus reliable and more portable) types `int16_t` and `int32_t`, too

Comment: I have mentioned in the answer that it's the case of 32 bit system. Also i mentioned the case of `int16_t` at the bottom

Comment: There is no ***guarantee*** of a 4 byte int! Not on a 32 bit system, not on a 64bit system. The specifications guarantee _at least 2 bytes, 16 bits_ for an int, no more no less. [See the types here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types)

Comment: Fine, only... jeez, there's so much to add to all of the answers, including mine (like how this only applies to arrays, the shift in memory is `sizeof(*ptr)` => `sizeof(type)`. I'm currently testing code, that makes me pedantic and cranky, sorry I was being a jerk just now

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem It's ok! don't care about it

Comment: Thanks, that diagram really makes it easy to understand it!!